# How to move a visible file to a hidden folder?

Tags: nautilus, directory

I've only been using Ubuntu for two weeks and have been able to find answers to any problem I had, however this one defies my searches.

I want to move a visible programme file (wallch) to a hidden directory ./config/autostart.  I have been able to enter this directory and the subject file is not there and I want to have this program start at bootup.

Can anyone assist?  Thanking you

Comment: Sorry, I want to copy the program file,not move.  Thanks

Comment: it's not `./config/autostart` , it's  `/.config/autostart`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, if you want a folder to be hidden, its name must too start with a `.` (dot) - the same thing is true for files. For example to create a hidden dolder, let say `.folder`, in your home directory from terminal, you can use the following command from terminal:

```
mkdir ~/.folder
```

Then to copy a file to this hidden folder, you can use the following command:

```
cp /path/to/file ~/.folder
```

To move a file in `.folder`:

```
mv /path/to/file ~/.folder
```

To list the content of `.folder`:

```
ll ~/.folder
```

(In Ubuntu `ll` is aliased to `ls -alF` in `.bashrc` file.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a newbie in Ubuntu myself, but maybe this will help you.

Go to Dash, type in "Startup Applications" go there, you'll see a dialog and the list of programs that are on startup . [image]

Click "Add" button > "Browse" [image]

and choose the program you want to be on startup. After you chose the program, give it a Name and a Comment, whatever you like (preferably something meaningful, so that you know what is the program and able to remove it from this list of you need).

I hope it will do the thing you want :)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I have installed conky for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Wallch developer here.
No need to mess with startup folders ;)

**For Wallch 4.0**

The startup options are enabled by default to the feature that was previously running. So only for one time, just activate the feature that you want to use on startup, minimize and that's it.

Wallch will start this feature on startup.

**For previous versions**

Wallch -> Preferences(CTRL+P)->Start up options and enable the option you want.

Comment: That is usefull information :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command,

```
cp /path/wallch /path/.config/autostart
```

`/path/wallch` - path to the wallch file

`/path/.config/autostart` - path to the autostart directory.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned a bit about the cp command because of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to copy it into /.config/autostart? That would stand for the .config folder of the 'root' account. For your account specifically the path should be ~/.config/autostart. Remember the 'tilda' symbol ~ stands for 'home directory'. For e.g. if your username is 'john', then ~ will point to /home/john and therefore ~/.config will be equivalent to /home/john/.config.